# The expression contained mismatched brackets

Tags: c++, regex

My program give me an error message: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::regex_error: The expression contained mismatched ( and )` and I can't find how fix it. What the brackets?

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace regex_constants;

int main() {
  // here can be url, or hashtag or split string: 
  // www.example.com or #followback or currentratesoughttogodown and output must be example or followback or currentratesoughttogodown.
  string input = "www.example.com"; 
  smatch m;
  regex_match ( input, m, regex ("(?<=www.|\\#)(\\w+)(?=\\.)?") );

  return 0;
}
```

I compile with`gcc`:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to the error, but I don't think it makes sense to have `?` after a lookahead group.

Comment: "Divide and conquer" - try pulling out the bracketed bits `(?<=www.|\\#)` etc and see which one gives you grief.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ can help with this. It reports "(?<= Lookbehind assertion is not fixed width" or "(? Invalid group structure" depending on the regex flavour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C++11  uses ECMAScript's (ECMA-262) regex syntax, so it will not have look-behind (other flavors of regex that C++11 supports also doesn't have look-behind).

`Lookahead` ie `(?=)` is supported though

You can probably try [`(?:www\\.|\\#)(\\w+)(?=\\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/10)

and grab the group 1 though.Or you can Look into using `Boost.Regex` or `Boost.Xpressive` which supports `lookbehind`.